# Background in an element in a listitem

Tags: android, listview, textview

I try to apply a background to a textview in an item of a listview.
I apply the background in the adapter :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   viewHolder.textview.setBackground(background);
   ...
}
```

Moreover, the layout width is setted like this :

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

And here is the xml of the background :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
         <solid android:color="#ff71b10c" />
         <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  </shape>
```

However, the background don't fit the width of the textview, i've tried several tips but nothing works.

You can see the bug here :

With bug : http://imageshack.us/a/img811/6742/3rx9.png

Without bug :http://imageshack.us/a/img14/9075/wfk8.png

I have no idea what that was about. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: does the textview has layout_width as match_parent?

Comment: Sorry i haven't specified, i've edit my question.

Comment: have you tried to call setbackgroundresource and pass it an id instead? or just set the background in the xml and see the results. you can also set the width to match_parent with margins and padding.

Comment: Can you show your code or xml of you background, please? Do you set background only when create new view?

Comment: what is your background object? is it a drawable png file or xml?

Comment: I've add the xml of the background ;) The background is setted every times when the view is gotten.

Comment: Wow, it's very strange but with setBackgroundResource the background works !
Thank you very much !

Comment: ok so vote yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't no why, but with setBackgroundResource the background fit the width correctly.

`viewHolder.textview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_id);`